# Android layout problems

Tags: android, layout, android-layout

I am obviously missing some little final bit of info here - within the main `RelativeLayout`, the 2nd/last item, the `LinearLayout` with the 2 images gets "pushed off" the screen by the `ViewFlipper`. If I specify a hard-coded height for the 2nd layout (the LinearLayout/MapView) inside the ViewFlipper, then the disappearing LinearLayout will show up, but of course that's not the way to do it.  Thanks for any pointers here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    a:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    a:layout_height="fill_parent"
    a:background="#ffffff" 
    a:id="@+id/layout_main">

    <ViewFlipper 
        a:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        a:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        a:id="@+id/MainFlipper">

        <ScrollView 
            a:id="@+id/ScrollView1" 
            a:layout_width="fill_parent"
            a:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout 
                a:orientation="vertical" 
                a:layout_width="fill_parent"
                a:background="#ffffff" 
                a:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TableLayout a:layout_width="wrap_content" a:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
                    a:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TableRow a:layout_height="wrap_content" a:layout_width="wrap_content">
                        <TextView a:layout_column="1" a:text="S" />
                        <Spinner a:id="@+id/SSpinner" a:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            a:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow a:layout_width="wrap_content" a:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <TextView a:layout_column="1" a:text="C" />
                        <Spinner a:id="@+id/CSpinner" a:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            a:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow a:layout_width="wrap_content" a:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <TextView a:layout_column="1" a:text="J" />
                        <Spinner a:id="@+id/JSpinner" a:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            a:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow a:layout_width="wrap_content" a:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <TextView a:layout_column="1" a:text="L" />
                        <Spinner a:id="@+id/LSpinner" a:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            a:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>
                <TextView a:text=" " a:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    a:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                <TextView a:text="Fill in only one field, then click Calculate"
                    a:layout_width="wrap_content" a:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                <TableLayout a:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    a:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TableRow a:layout_height="wrap_content" a:layout_width="wrap_content">
                        <TextView a:layout_column="1" a:text="Price1 ($)" />
                        <EditText a:layout_width="200px" a:inputType="numberDecimal"
                            a:id="@+id/P1EditText" a:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            a:cursorVisible="false" />
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow a:layout_width="wrap_content" a:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <TextView a:layout_column="1" a:text="Page" />
                        <EditText a:layout_width="wrap_content" a:inputType="number"
                            a:id="@+id/PageNoEditText" a:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow a:layout_width="wrap_content" a:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <TextView a:layout_column="1" a:text="Price2 ($)" />
                        <EditText a:layout_width="wrap_content" a:inputType="numberDecimal"
                            a:id="@+id/P2EditText" a:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>
                <TextView a:id="@+id/E1TextView" a:text=" "
                    a:layout_width="wrap_content" a:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                <TableLayout a:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    a:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TableRow a:layout_height="wrap_content" a:layout_width="wrap_content">
                        <Button a:onClick="ClickCalculateButton" a:text="Calculate"
                            a:id="@+id/CalculateButton" a:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            a:layout_width="wrap_content" />
                        <Button a:onClick="ClickClearButton" a:text="Clear Fields"
                            a:id="@+id/ClearButton" a:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            a:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <LinearLayout 
            a:id="@+id/ScrollView2" 
            a:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            a:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <com.google.android.maps.MapView 
                a:id="@+id/mapView"
                a:enabled="true" 
                a:clickable="true" 
                a:layout_width="fill_parent"
                a:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                a:apiKey="my-key" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ViewFlipper>

    <LinearLayout 
        a:layout_below="@+id/MainFlipper"
        a:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        a:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        a:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        a:gravity="bottom|center" 
        a:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ImageView 
            a:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            a:layout_width="wrap_content"
            a:id="@+id/imageView1" 
            a:src="@drawable/btn_toggle_on" />
        <ImageView 
            a:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            a:layout_width="wrap_content"
            a:id="@+id/imageView2" 
            a:src="@drawable/btn_toggle_off" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: could it be that your map view occupies all the height available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `a:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"` to your flipper and remove `a:layout_below="@+id/MainFlipper"` from your last linear layout. Also, it could be easier to achieve with `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: That's crazy.  Why would one work and not the other?  (Is this a bug?)

Comment: No, this isn't bug, it's logically. Your approach doesn't restrict  upper layout (flipper) as he doesn't even know about second layout, and takes all the space he can.